# Remove hover and default state from jquery ui button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a set of anchors that I am converting to buttons like so:

```
var sideMenuAnchors = $("#divLeft a");
sideMenuAnchors.width("120px");
sideMenuAnchors.button();
```

However when one of these anchors is clicked I want the `ui-state-active` to remain until another button is clicked ... I have been unable to find a simple solution, is there one ?

I have tried this:

```
$('#anchor01').unbind('onmouseover').unbind('onmouseout');
```

and this :

```
$('#anchor01').disable()
```

However neither do what I require, as the `ui-active-state` is still removed on `mouseout`

*Edit*
The solution I implemented was to manually add the button classes that I required from jquery-ui, like so:

```
var sideMenuAnchors = $("#divLeft a");
    sideMenuAnchors.addClass("ui-state-default ui-button ui-button-text-only");
    sideMenuAnchors.width("120px");
    sideMenuAnchors.height("25px");
    sideMenuAnchors.removeClass('ui-corner-all');
    sideMenuAnchors.first().addClass('ui-corner-top');
    sideMenuAnchors.last().addClass('ui-corner-bottom');
    sideMenuAnchors.hover( function() {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        },function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You have mixed code and selectors. Please provide the HTML code and state which anchor should remain active until which button is clicked.

Comment: @Shef, the clicked anchor should remain active ... not sure what you mean re:"mixed code" its all javascript.

Comment: In your particular case which one would be the clicked anchor and which one would remove the active state of the clicked button? Provide some meaningful code.

Comment: @Shef, It doesn't matter which anchor, its not the process of selecting the anchor that is the problem. Its the means of removing mouseout behaviour (defined by jquery-ui button) that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're transforming hyperlinks into jQuery UI buttons, there are no group relationship between them and they're all considered as independent.

However, if you were transforming *radio buttons* (with the same `name` attribute), then jQuery UI would maintain the group relationship and you would obtain the behavior you're aiming for.

So, you can do just that: first, add a radio button and its associated label to each hyperlink, then transform these into buttons:

```
<form>
    <div id="divLeft">
        <a id="link1" href="#">Foo</a>
        <a id="link2" href="#">Bar</a>
        <a id="link3" href="#">Quux</a>
    </div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divLeft a").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var text = $this.text();
        var radioId = $this.attr("id") + "_radio";
        $this.text("").append(
            $("<input type='radio' name='buttons'>").attr("id", radioId),
            $("<label>").attr("for", radioId).text(text));
    });

    $("#divLeft a input:radio").width("120px").button();
});
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrYYb/).

Comment: Thanks, Is the anchor behaviour retained, will the link still work ?

Comment: @Nim, it's still there in the document, we're only adding content to it, so it should still work.

Comment: I don't think it does, the jsfiddle didn't anyway :-(

Comment: @Nim, well, all the links in the fiddle have their `href` attributes set to `#`, so clicking them won't do anything. Did you try with your own `href` attributes?

Comment: I changed your fiddle to different href attributes and it didn't work. Hang on, I am talking out my a55 it does work. Ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: false alarm, it is still there as a link (you can right click and follow link) but default click behaviour has changed, left clicking does not follow link

Comment: @Nim, strange, left clicking does follow the link in my tests. Which browser are you using?

Comment: the fiddle (with link altered to google) does not work in chrome or ie

Comment: I found a solution, bit messy, but will add edit question anyway